# Trouble using pointers with array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm new to C and having a problem with pointers. I've been unable to find the answer online or through my peers, so here I am.

I've been given an assignment to:

- Create an array of 20 random integers
- print out the integers
- sort the array in ascending order
- print it out again

When I compile the program with GCC and run, I get a segmentation fault. I've narrowed it down to happening when I try and set the value of `number[i]` or `number[k]` in the `sort` function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int* number, int n){
     /*Sort the given array number , of length n*/
    int temp, min;
    int i, k;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        min = i;
        for(k=i+1; k<n; k++){
            if(number[k]<min){
                min = k;
            }
        }
        temp = number[i];
        number[i] = number[k];
        number[k] = temp;
    }   
}

int main(){
    /*Declare an integer n and assign it a value of 20.*/
    int n=20;

    /*Allocate memory for an array of n integers using malloc.*/
    int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(array));

    /*Fill this array with random numbers, using rand().*/
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        array[i] = rand()%1000+1;
    }

    /*Print the contents of the array.*/
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    /*Pass this array along with n to the sort() function of part a.*/
    sort(&array, 20);

    /*Print the contents of the array.*/
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the compile errors I get:

> Q3.c: In function âmainâ:
>
> Q3.c:31: warning: implicit declaration of function âmallocâ
>
> Q3.c:31: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in
>   function âmallocâ
>
> Q3.c:34: warning: implicit declaration of function âsrandâ
>
> Q3.c:34: warning: implicit declaration of function âtimeâ
>
> Q3.c:37: warning: implicit declaration of function ârandâ
>
> Q3.c:46: warning: passing argument 1 of âsortâ from incompatible
>   pointer type
>
> Q3.c:9: note: expected âint *â but argument is of type âint **â

Comment: You don't need dynamic allocation for your problem. An array of 20 integers is `int[20]`.

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is not rite you meant `sizeof(*array)`?. moreover "<stdlib.h>" is necessary for malloc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point where you swap elements,

```
temp = number[i];
number[i] = number[k];
number[k] = temp;
```

`k == n` because it's after the end of

```
for(k=i+1; k<n; k++){
```

You meant to use `min` instead of `k` in the swap.

In `main`,

```
int *array = malloc(n * sizeof(array));
```

allocates enough space for `n` pointers to `int`, not space for 20 `int`. That should be

```
int *array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
```

With regard to the compiler warnings/errors,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and call

```
sort(array, 20);
```

instead of passing `&array`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I also missed that if(number[k]<min) should have been if(number[k]<number[min])

Answer (score 0):

`array` is an `int*`, your `sort` function is expecting an `int*`, yet you pass `&array`, the address of the int pointer